# angular is not defined(anonymous function) @ md-data-table.min.js:1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

this is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS material-sidenav Plunker</title>
    <!-- style sheet -->
    <link href="bower_components/angular-material-data-table/dist/md-data-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <!-- module -->

        module -->
   <!--   <link href="/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material-data-table/dist/md-data-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
module -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index3.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material-data-table/dist/md-data-table.min.css"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material-data-table/dist/md-data-table.css"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material-data-table/dist/md-data-table.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material-data-table/dist/md-data-table-style.css"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material-data-table/dist/md-data-table.js"></script>


</head>

<body >

<div ng-app="exampleApp" ng-controller="ExampleController" layout-margin>
    <mdt-table>
        <mdt-header-row>
            <mdt-column align-rule="left">Dessert (100g serving)</mdt-column>
            <mdt-column align-rule="right">Calories</mdt-column>
            <mdt-column align-rule="right">Fat (g)</mdt-column>
            <mdt-column align-rule="right">Carbs (g)</mdt-column>
            <mdt-column align-rule="right">Protein (g)</mdt-column>
            <mdt-column align-rule="right">Sodium (mg)</mdt-column>
            <mdt-column align-rule="right">Calcium (%)</mdt-column>
            <mdt-column align-rule="right">Iron (%)</mdt-column>
        </mdt-header-row>
        <mdt-row ng-repeat="nutrition in nutritionList">
            <mdt-cell>{{nutrition.name}}</mdt-cell>
            <mdt-cell>{{nutrition.calories}}</mdt-cell>
            <mdt-cell>{{nutrition.fat}}</mdt-cell>
            <mdt-cell>{{nutrition.carbs}}</mdt-cell>
            <mdt-cell>{{nutrition.protein}}</mdt-cell>
            <mdt-cell>{{nutrition.sodium}}</mdt-cell>
            <mdt-cell>{{nutrition.calcium}}</mdt-cell>
            <mdt-cell>{{nutrition.iron}}</mdt-cell>
        </mdt-row>
    </mdt-table>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

this is index3.js

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular.module('exampleApp', ['ngMaterial', 'mdDataTable']);
    angular.module('exampleApp').controller('ExampleController', function($scope, $mdToast){

        $scope.nutritionList = [
            {
                id: 601,
                name: 'Frozen joghurt',
                calories: 159,
                fat: 6.0,
                carbs: 24,
                protein: 4.0,
                sodium: 87,
                calcium: '14%',
                iron: '1%'
            },
            {
                id: 602,
                name: 'Ice cream sandwitch',
                calories: 237,
                fat: 9.0,
                carbs: 37,
                protein: 4.3,
                sodium: 129,
                calcium: '84%',
                iron: '1%'
            },
            {
                id: 603,
                name: 'Eclair',
                calories: 262,
                fat: 16.0,
                carbs: 24,
                protein: 6.0,
                sodium: 337,
                calcium: '6%',
                iron: '7%'
            },
            {
                id: 604,
                name: 'Cupkake',
                calories: 305,
                fat: 3.7,
                carbs: 67,
                protein: 4.3,
                sodium: 413,
                calcium: '3%',
                iron: '8%'
            },
            {
                id: 605,
                name: 'Gingerbread',
                calories: 356,
                fat: 16.0,
                carbs: 49,
                protein: 2.9,
                sodium: 327,
                calcium: '7%',
                iron: '16%'
            },
            {
                id: 606,
                name: 'Jelly bean',
                calories: 375,
                fat: 0.0,
                carbs: 94,
                protein: 0.0,
                sodium: 50,
                calcium: '0%',
                iron: '0%'
            },
            {
                id: 607,
                name: 'Lollipop',
                calories: 392,
                fat: 0.2,
                carbs: 98,
                protein: 0,
                sodium: 38,
                calcium: '0%',
                iron: '2%'
            },
            {
                id: 608,
                name: 'Honeycomb',
                calories: 408,
                fat: 3.2,
                carbs: 87,
                protein: 6.5,
                sodium: 562,
                calcium: '0%',
                iron: '45%'
            },
            {
                id: 609,
                name: 'Donut',
                calories: 452,
                fat: 25.0,
                carbs: 51,
                protein: 4.9,
                sodium: 326,
                calcium: '2%',
                iron: '22%'
            },
            {
                id: 610,
                name: 'KitKat',
                calories: 518,
                fat: 26.0,
                carbs: 65,
                protein: 7,
                sodium: 54,
                calcium: '12%',
                iron: '6%'
            }
        ];
    });
}());
```

But i got those errors:

```
        angular.js:29659 WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.
md-data-table.min.css:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
md-data-table.css:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
md-data-table-style.css:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=exampleApp&p1=Error…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A463)
```

Others are librariesbower components.

So, what am i doing wrong? I want to see just a simple table. But i got errors. Those are libraries it downloaded, why errors?

ihave lots of libraries but i dont use all. 
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-animate
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-aria
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-aria/.bower.json
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js.map
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-aria/bower.json
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-aria/index.js
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-aria/package.json
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-aria/README.md
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material/demos
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material/modules
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material/.bower.json
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material/.gitignore
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.css
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.layouts.css
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.layouts.min.css
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.min.css
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.min.js
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.scss
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material/angular-material-mocks.js
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material/bower.json
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material/CHANGELOG.md
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material/index.js
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material/LICENSE
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material/package.json
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material/README.md
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material-data-table
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material-data-table/dist
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material-data-table/dist/md-data-table.css
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material-data-table/dist/md-data-table.js
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material-data-table/dist/md-data-table.min.css
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material-data-table/dist/md-data-table.min.js
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material-data-table/dist/md-data-table-style.css
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material-data-table/.bower.json
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material-data-table/bower.json
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material-data-table/CHANGELOG.md
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material-data-table/index.js
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material-data-table/LICENSE.md
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material-data-table/package.json
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material-data-table/README.md
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-material-icons
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-messages
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-mocks
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/angular-sanitize
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/jquery
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/lodash
    /home/caneraydin/IdeaProjects/InternetMovieDatabase/src/main/resources/static/bower_components/mdDataTable

Comment: where have u defined angularjs?

Comment: here <script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/…; – any help

Answer (score 0):

Try putting https:// in front of the angular link

Comment: still md-data-table.min.css:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
md-data-table.css:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
md-data-table-style.css:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=exampleApp&p1=Error…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A463)

Answer (score 0):

My Guess is one of the injection is causing you the error...

```
angular.module('exampleApp', ['ngMaterial', 'mdDataTable']);
    angular.module('exampleApp').controller('ExampleController', function($scope, $mdToast){
```

It could be the `ngMaterial` library not being added and you trying to inject it... can you check this...

I don't see angular-material there...

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Do an bower install angular-material --save and you should have the dependency and then you can add angular-material which would throw of the error.

Comment: i dont know how to add it. i added angular-aria.min.js and angular-aria.js because it depends on them they say.

Comment: i already had angulararia but  added material. But i dont know which one to put first, i put angular first. Do i have to use src="bower_compo" or src="myprocect/src/etc" because they are always working. i got again errors. angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=exampleApp&p1=Error…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A463)

Comment: @j.doe: can you share me your complete poc... so that i can run it here and fix the issue...

Answer (score 0):

Can you please raise this issue in the repository itself? You might get a faster answer-fix!

http://iamisti.github.io/mdDataTable/